# How to iterate through selected row at WPF datagrid and read both cell content and cell column name

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Ok i can not find a way to iterate through selected row in DataGrid WPF and read both selected row cell values and that particular cell column name

How can i do that ?

This is how DataGrid is binded in the first place

```
DataTable dtSelectedTableValues = DbConnection.db_Select_DataTable("select * from " + cbTableNames.SelectedValue.ToString());
dgSelectedTableValues.ItemsSource = dtSelectedTableValues.DefaultView;
```

What i want is simple

For example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s1cP.png) i want to iterate at this selected row

**So i want to read**

First : `clRootSiteId` as a column name and `4` as a cell value

Second : `clSiteRootUrl` as a column name and `http://www.gold.com.tr` as a cell value

```
.
.
.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `DefaultView` as `ItemsSource`, the source type will be [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and each item in `SelectedItems` is [`DataRowView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Use string property index of `DataRowView` that accepts column name, [`Item[String]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k5w061k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var items = dtSelectedTableValues.SelectedItems;
foreach (DataRowView item in items)
{
    var clRootSiteId = item["clRootSiteId"];
    var clSiteRootUrl = item["clSiteRootUrl"];
}
```